# Redirection to Heroku : 502 Proxy Error for static files (Django app)

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku https://omegapp3.herokuapp.com and a custom domain [association-omega.com](http://association-omega.com/) that I configured to be redirected on the Heroku app.
When I go on [association-omega.com](http://association-omega.com/), the first page (`index.html`) is well served but for all of the static files, I have a 502 Proxy Error. Do you know if there are any prerequisite for static files ? (I use `whitenoise` to serve static files).